# Get value from pom.xml into a yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, swagger, pom.xml, openapi

I am using swagger ui and im trying to read some properties in pom.xml into yaml file (Like version, artifactId for example), but i am get this error:

**Parser error on line 3
bad indentation of a mapping entry**

[Full error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeYpq.png)

The head of my openapi.yaml file. I need to use the artifactId in the title.

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: @artifactId@
```

Do i need to make something with the pom.xml? Export the file? Or there is another way to retrieve data from pom.xml?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the resource filtering functionality provided by maven. [link to doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Change your openapi.yaml file to:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: ${artifactId}
```

And add the following section to your pom.xml. (assuming that your openapi.yaml is in the resources directory)

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Maven build will create an openapi.yaml file with the substituted artifactId in the target directory.

Answer (score 2):

try using single quote:

```
api:
    version: '@project.version@'
```

and inside the `pom.xml`,

```
<project>
    ...
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another important thing!

If you have using some certificate or binaries files, it's also important to configure something like:

```
`<plugins>
    <!-- allow resource files to contain references to Maven properties like ${prop.name} -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
          <!-- exclude all binary files from filtering! -->
          <nonFilteredFileExtension>p12</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          <nonFilteredFileExtension>crt</nonFilteredFileExtension>
          <nonFilteredFileExtension>pem</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>`
```

Because can be you corrupt your certs if you don't do this.